# How to Import MySQL database to SOLR

Tags: mysql, solr, xampp

I'm trying to import my **mysql** database to **SOLR** (i'm following the only tutorial which looks complete http://entropytc.com/importing-a-mysql-database-into-apache-solr/) but i don't understand the SQL queries part.. have i to select all columns that i have ? and i don't find the **solr/example/solr/conf** directory..
Do you have any idea about this ?
Thank you :)

Comment: are you using solr with source code or you have dloaded the one without source code having the jars only?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I wouldn't import anything. I'd load solr with "documents" that are heavily denormalized views containing everything the calling code needs to render them. That does require code though afaik.

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest Solr [here](http://ftp.itu.edu.tr/Mirror/Apache/lucene/solr/4.0.0/apache-solr-4.0.0.zip) which contains the example directory. Most probably you downloaded the Solr source code, so that it doesn't contain examples.

For your second question, No you don't have to select all columns. You should select the one you need to index/store in the Solr.

For more information check [Solr Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler). It has explains this in detail.